# How can I access a specific element in a std::map with more than 2 elements?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am trying to access a specific element out of a std::map with more than two elements. Here is an example:

```
std::map <int, CString, CString, CString> map;

//Initialise

map[0] = _T("stuff1"), _T("stuff2"), _T("stuff3");

//now if I just want to access stuff3 is it this:

CString str = map[0][2];

//or something more like this?

CString str = map[0]. ???
```

Any help would be great thanks.

edit: Thanks sorry about that, first time using maps, I was wondering why I couldn't find any information on std::map 's with more elements inside.

Comment: `std::map <int, CString, CString, CString>` -- that's not how a `std::map` works, or any container for that matter. Only the second type is the value type. If you need multiple values, make it a `tuple` or a simple `struct`/`class`.

Comment: would it be better to use something like:

std::map <int, std::tuple<CString, CString, CString>>

Comment: @user1622275, Seeing as how they're all `CString`, a `tuple` doesn't fit as well as `array` or `vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to compile this? It shouldn't.
You can create only a map with exactly 1 key and 1 value for each element.

But the value can be compound, so you can write

```
struct ValueType {
 CString v1;
 CString v2;
 CString v3;
}
std::map <int, ValueType> map;
```

and access elements like `map[somekey].v3;`

To insert a value in such a map, you'll have to write

```
ValueType strings = {"1","2","3"};
map.insert(999, strings);
```

Or you may create a helper function (i.e. `void addToMap(std::map <int, ValueType> &map, CSting const& v1, CString const& v2, CString const& v3)` ), which will fill your map in a more convenient way.

Comment: `map[somekey].v3`, you don't get the `pair` back.

Answer (score 3):

`std::map <int, CString, CString, CString> map;` is illegal.

Either use a `std::multimap` or a `std::map<int,std::vector<CString> >`.

Comment: Or `std::map<int, std::array<CString, 3>>`, seeing as how the size is definitely known.

Comment: multimap is about multiple keys allowed, not a tuple for values.

Comment: @Dani: Actually, having "multiple keys" is the basic premise for using `std::(whatever)map`. It *does* mean that one key can map to multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this what you are looking for

```
std::map <int, std::list<CString> > myMap;
```

then you'll access `myMap[0]`, then access each element in the returned `std::list<CString>`

Comment: A list is the least fortunate data structure here, as access time is linear.